# NSFetchRequest: Fetching max value for multiple items

Tags: ios, core-data, group-by, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I am having trouble creating the correct predicate for a fetch that gets max values of multiple items. The scenario:

**Entity**: Grades

**Properties**: StudentId, Grade, GivenOn (Date), Status

**Goal**: When getting a list of student IDs, retrieve the latest grade for each student (together with other grade properties that are needed for each grade row).

**Constraints**: (1) Students may have 0, 1 or more grades, (2) a single result must be returned for each student, with the latest grade if there is more than one (3) I don't have access to the Student entity, so I cannot use a relationship to fetch the grades.

Here's my unsuccessful attempt:

```
    let studentIDs = ["101", "102", "103", ...]
    let fetch = NSFetchRequest<GradeModel>(entityName: "GradeModel")
    fetch.predicate = NSPredicate(
          format: "student_id IN %@", studentIDs)
    fetch.resultType = .dictionaryResultType

    // get latest grade - grouped by student-id
    let maxExpression = NSExpression(format: "max:(givenOn)")
    let givenOnEx = NSExpressionDescription()
    givenOnEx.expression = maxExpression
    givenOnEx.name = "maxGivenOn"
    givenOnEx.expressionResultType = .dateAttributeType

    fetch.propertiesToFetch = [givenOnEx, "student_id", "grade", "status"]
    fetch.propertiesToGroupBy = ["student_id", "grade", "status"]
    fetch.sortDescriptors = [
          NSSortDescriptor(key: "given_on", ascending: false)
    ]
```

I get correct results only if I list "student_id" in "propertiesToFetch"/"propertiesToGroupBy", however I need all fields for all grades. When I list the other fields like in the example above, then I occasionally get multiple grades per student - depending on the grouped-by values.

I could obviously get the latest grade row one student at the time, but that would be inefficient for a large number of students.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't have access to the Student entity, so I cannot use a relationship to fetch the grades." - is there some fundamental reason that you can't fetch by student?

Comment: The Student entity is not a Core Data entity, so I can't add Grades as a relationship to it.

Comment: is there any reason you can't make it one?

Comment: Not really. The source of the data is external and the overhead of maintaining a duplicate copy doesn't make sense.